# why does global in a class behave differently when the class is within a function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget, ginput

I'm trying to use `ginput` to register clicks on a map, and wanted to add action buttons using matplotlib widgets.  In the following code, I can pass back the value of action to the main code by declaring it a `global`. If I click on the map, action=0, if I click on the button, action=1, as desired.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class Index:
    def test(self, event):
        global action
        action=1

# fake data
x=np.arange(30)
y=x**2
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
callback = Index()
buttonname=['test']
colors=['white']
idx=[0.2]
bax,buttons={},{}

# set up list of buttons.
for i,col,button in zip(idx,colors,buttonname):
    bax[button] = plt.axes([0.92, i, 0.07, 0.07])
    buttons[button] = Button(bax[button],button,color=col,hovercolor='green')
    buttons[button].on_clicked(getattr(callback,button))

# register click on plot
while True:
     pts=plt.ginput(1)
     plt.pause(0.5)
     print("action is ",action)
     action=0 # reset
```

But my confusion is, if I take the exact same code and place it in a def block, the value of action is no longer passed back, `action` is always zero.

```
def subtest():
    class Index:
        def test(self, event):
            global action
            action=1

    # fake data
    action=0
    x=np.arange(30)
    y=x**2
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,y)
    callback = Index()
    buttonname=['test']
    colors=['white']
    idx=[0.2]
    bax,buttons={},{}

    # set up list of buttons.
    for i,col,button in zip(idx,colors,buttonname):
        bax[button] = plt.axes([0.92, i, 0.07, 0.07])
        buttons[button] = Button(bax[button],button,color=col,hovercolor='green')
        buttons[button].on_clicked(getattr(callback,button))

    # register click on plot
    while True:
         pts=plt.ginput(1)
         plt.pause(0.5)
         print("action is ",action)
         action=0 # reset

res=subtest()
```

I'm very confused as to why this happens.  I tried moving the class definition out into the main code but that didn't help.  I'm happy for any kind of solution (e.g. passing action through an argument, which I have not understood how to do with widgets), as I think that the use of `global` is often frowned apon.  But also a `global` -based solution is fine.

Comment: You've declared ``action`` as ``global`` in the scope ``subtest.Index.test`` but not inside the scope ``subtest``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`action` inside `subtest` is local to subtest, while `action` inside `Index.test` is global. Either declare `action` global in `subtest`, or use [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) in `Index.test`.

(I suspect there may be better solutions without globals, but since I'm not familiar with the GUI toolkit I'll leave that to someone else.)

Comment: hmmm, in fact I tried that before posting, but declaring action as global within subtest didn't help.  However, the nonlocal statement worked !  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you want to check out this article [on closures](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure) and [this other article on closures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-closures/). I think you need to declare action outside of both your class and functions and then reference it with global in the class.

I don't think you need to use a class - you can get away with passing a variable, boolean, dictionary around functions and achieve the same thing.

You can use the "on_click" event to do what you want see this widget tutorial [widget tutorial](https://blog.finxter.com/matplotlib-widgets-button/) and [this on matplotlib event handling](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html)

Here is an example piece of code using "global" to effect state changes. Better to pass around a variable or use the event to trigger whatever you want the state to effect.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

state = False

def change_state(btn_action):
    #do something
    btn_action= not(btn_action)
    return btn_action

def grid(val):
    global state
    #do something
    state =change_state(state)
    print(state)

    ax.grid()
    fig.canvas.draw()

    #reset value
    state =change_state(state)
    print(f'resetting state to {state}')

# fake data
x=np.arange(30)
y=x**2

#create fig, ax
fig =plt.figure()
ax= fig.subplots()
p, = ax.plot(x,y)

# set up list of buttons.

buttonname=['test']
colors=['white']
idx=[0.2]
bax,buttons={},{}

for i,col,button in zip(idx,colors,buttonname):
    bax[button] = plt.axes([0.92, i, 0.07, 0.07])
    buttons[button] = Button(bax[button],button,color=col,hovercolor='green')
    buttons[button].on_clicked(grid)

#show plot
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.show()
```